# Getting mouse events

Tags: c#, mouse, user32

I'm working in C# and would like to get all the mouse events. What is the best why to do so.
I tried:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
```

I couldn't make it to work and it's limited to a single module, and I would like to get all the mouse events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a Global Hook. Here's a code project article about doing that:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx